# PHP, Open local url with fopen

Tags: php, url, fopen

How to url fopen local file? Because this is not working on my hosting

`fopen("saver.php", "r");`

It just opens the file for read, not for execute.

I need this to start parallel process. PHP threads and `pecl` don't work on the hosting.  Options are curl and fopen. But curl is waiting for a response.

Using `fopen("http://myserver.com/saver.php", "r");` is not good for me. Because this request is quite slow, for starting parallel process. I want just local fopen, without sending request to outside and than back to hosting.

Comment: Parallel process? How did you think that with `fopen` you can do such a thing on your environment? `fopen` is not for execution however. You need sufficient permissions to run system commands. As I'm aware that's the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute this you need use `system` not `open`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: well, but I dont have access with php to use system cmds

Answer (score 0):

Using a local name of the local machine should work, doesn't it?

```
fopen("http://localhost/saver.php", "r");
```

Or maybe even

```
require('saver.php')
```

Comment: Problem is the hosting where is my page http://localhost not working. I want just open paralell process with fopen. When I use `fopen http://myserver.com/saver.php` this request takes quit long. I know just relative path to file and external url adress. 
`require('saver.php')` doesnt help because I need paralell process.
c

Comment: Doesn't fopen("http://127.0.0.1/saver.php", "r") work any better? Or with the local ip address of the host?